# How to configure Google App Engine cron tasks in Node?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I'm new to GAE. I have a Node application that only handles one URL for now, which should be called as a cron.

I have the following cron.yaml file:

```
cron:
- description: "Test"
  url: /translations
  schedule: every 15 minutes
```

And here is the handlers section of my app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
```

If I call the URL manually, it works and returns a 200 response.

But my job isn't launched, and it isn't listed in the task queue in the Google console either. Do you have an idea about what is missing?

Comment: Did you deploy the cron file? Do you see it in the [developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/taskqueues/cron)?

Comment: I did deploy it (and when I debug the code I can see the file), but I don't see it in the developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `app.yaml` and `cron.yaml` config files look fine. You should verify the following:

1. Try to redeploy the `cron.yaml` and specify your project ID just to ensure you have it going to the right project:

   ```
   gcloud app deploy cron.yaml --project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID
   ```
2. Verify the job deployed using [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/taskqueues/cron?project=_&tab=CRON), which will ask you to select your project. Choose the same project that you specified on the command line.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to use the Logging pages to debug or inspect cron deployments, which seems like missing audit functionality.